# Vkontakte HTTP API returns 'Incorrect signature'

Tags: vk

I have a problem using Vkontakte HTTP API. I'm trying to use the 'audio.search' method with my own VK application but with no success.

A friend gave me an 'api_id', 'api_secret' and 'viewer_id' to test my code and works perfectly, but when I try to use the data from my own application it just returns "Incorrect signature: iframe/flash authorization".

I'm using my user id as the 'viewer_id', my application id as 'api_id'  and the secure key of the application as 'api_secret'.

Am I doing anything wrong? I can't find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your signature is wrong. Check it manually. And also how the signature is generated?

Comment: I don't think the signature is wrong. With another account (not created by me) it just works fine. I'm using the method VK says to generate the signature: MD5(viewer_id + parameters + api_secret), with the parameters sorted alphabetically and no '&'.

Comment: Maybe it happens because of user permissions settings?

Comment: No idea to be honest. Where I can set the permission settings? The user I use as viewer is set as application administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Try new API. It don't requires signature... Check this: http://vk.com/dev/audio.search

Sample request:

https://api.vk.com/method/audio.search.xml?access_token=TOKEN&q=Ke%24ha+-+C%27Mon&count=1&sort=2&v=5.5

Just replace **TOKEN** with your token